# About Custom TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

Here are two custom `UITabBarViewController` demos

[BrowserTabViewDemo](https://github.com/xxhp/BrowserTabViewDemo)

[AKTabBarController](https://github.com/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController)

I always use `UITabBarController` to make custom tabbar , but these two project use `UIViewController` to management another viewcontrollers not `UITbarBarController`.

**My question is how to management many viewcontrollers by one `UIViewController` . and what is different `UITabBarviewcontroller`？**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITabBarController is one of Apple's pre-made container controllers, as is UINavigationController. You can make your own custom container controller using the methods in the "Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container" section of the UIViewController Class reference. There is a video in the WWDC 2011 sessions called "Implementing UIViewController Containment" -- that's a good place to learn about this subject.